Why do grid-based simulations of the wave equation form perfect circles?
Here is a simple wave simulation: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sd3WB
Every frame, the value of each pixel is accelerated proportionally by the difference between its value and the average value of its four neighboring pixels. (This code is in Buffer B.)
Since this is such a grid-based simulation, seemingly following taxicab geometry, I would expect the result to have a "square" bias. But the waves are extremely circular, and they seem to become more perfectly circular as they spread.
Why does a square grid simulation like this give rise to such perfect circles?
